# Difference between two tables in sum of rows based on new col created OR compared to existing col

Tags: c#, sql, u-sql

So I've got two tables, with the same columns, which I want to compare two specific columns between them for data difference. **First approach is not equal to the Second approach**, the second approach being the correct one, why?

- **First approach**: Add a column called tag equals 1 on both. Then do a inner join on these column: SUM (A.fq1 - B.fq2)
  If there's a result, then there's a difference.
- **Second approach**:
  One existing column which I can do the inner join on is ProductId. Then same approach but Inner join condition is on ProductId. Resulting for each productId the substraction of all.

The second approach shows me correctly the difference between both tables, for each specific ProductId. But the first one doesn't, which shows me for overall rows. Why is this?

**First approach** code:
For better context on this example: table3 == (table2-table1)

```
   out0 =
    SELECT 
        SUM(fq1) AS fq1,
        SUM(fq2) AS fq2,
           1 AS Tag
    FROM table3
    WHERE Date == @DayToValidate;
 
out1 =
    SELECT 
        SUM(fq1) AS fq1,
        SUM(fq2) AS fq2,
           1 AS Tag
    FROM table1;
 
out2 =
    SELECT 
        SUM(fq1) AS fq1,
        SUM(fq2) AS fq2,
           1 AS Tag
    FROM table2;
 
out3 =
    SELECT 
        (A.fq1- B.fq1) AS fq1diff,
        (A.fq2- B.fq2) AS fq2diff,
           1 AS Tag
    FROM out2 AS A
         INNER JOIN
             out1 AS B
         ON A.Tag == B.Tag;

 
out4 =
    SELECT (A.fq1diff - B.fq1) AS fq1Diff,
           (A.fq2diff - B.fq2) AS fq2Diff,
           1 AS Tag
    FROM out3 AS A
         INNER JOIN
             out0 AS B
         ON A.Tag == B.Tag;
```

Comment: I cannot tell from your question which is the first approach and which is the second.

Comment: The code shown is the first approach. The second is the same but instead of being a inner join on the new column tag it is on ProductId

Comment: Your first approach doesn't create a link between two tables for specific rows but attempts to check if there is a difference on the sums of fq1 and fq2 columns (and tag itself is useless with a constant 1) regardless of other fields (whole table).

Second approach creates the link through a common Id field. Overall it is not clear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thank you for your comment. I'm trying to validate two columns, making sure they have same information between two different tables (table3 vs table2 - table1). First filtering data I just need, hence table2 - table1 and then comparing result by SUM subtraction on table3. Both approaches aim for this, validating content is the same.

Comment: @Vesper, sorry I cannot still understand. Why wouldn't you add some sample data that shows what your data looks like and the output you want to get? Everybody would then have a good understanding of your requirement.